# Request focus on Button on SoftKeyboard

Tags: android

Does Android keyboard supports focus on Button or View by setting android:nextFocusDown in Edittext? If not, how to request on Button when user click on next button in SoftKeyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you can try.

```
editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(final TextView textView, final int i, final KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (i== EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){
                editText.clearFocus();
                button.requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
    button.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onFocusChange(final View view, final boolean b) {
            if (view.isFocused()){
                button.setBackgroundResource(R.color.colorAccent);
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does android support setting in xml?

Comment: you can have nextfocusdown but that won't work for buttons and you have to get it using java code only.

Comment: I have 2 EditTexts and a button. I implemented code with second EditText but UI not focus on Button, it focus on first EditText